# PDO: Binding Values Wrapped in Single Quotes for MATCH() Query

Tags: php, mysql, database, binding, pdo

I'm having some difficulty with implementing `fulltext()` searching into my queries. Now the parameters in the `AGAINST()` segment won't invoke an error - unless they're wrapped in single-quotes.

**Error**: `PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Which makes sense as they shouldn't be literals, instead, they should be strings, so the values aren't be bound, right? But in order for this query to function the parameters in `AGAINST()` must be surrounded by single quotes.

```
MATCH(features) AGAINST(':feature_set :feature_unset')

$bind_array[":feature_set"] = $feature_set;
$bind_array[":feature_unset"] = $feature_unset;

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($bind_array);
```

---

`:feature_set :feature_unset`

Would return a string formatted like so:

> +Softaculous -Free Domain -Site Builder -Fantastico

Does anyone know of a solution for this? Much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way

```php
$query = '... MATCH(features) AGAINST(:against IN BOOLEAN MODE)';

$bind_array[":against"] = $feature_set . ' ' . $feature_unset;

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($bind_array);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d93bc/6)** demo.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I can't implement this as the query has many other parameters other than the `match()` one, also the  `$bind_array` is slowly built up as each condition is met. Would you mind explaining your answer and why it'd work, it could held solving this. Thanks again :)

Comment: `AGAINST` expect the only string expression. Therefore you have to have one bound parameter and shouldn't use quotes around a placeholder. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, this works a treat. Just as a reference i guess i should add that i found another solution too. The solution was to concatenate the single quotes to the variables themselves. Overall though, @peterm 's answer provided a cleaner solution, so i went with that.

Comment: On a separate note Peter, does your answer infer that appending `IN BOOLEAN MODE` to the variables in `AGAINST()` is not required?

Comment: You're welcome. Make `IN BOOLEAN MODE` just part of the query. See updated answer. You can also see that in the sqlfiddle that I provided with equivalent sql code.